# Upload file in sharepoint document library using ECMA script

Tags: file-upload, file

I Want to upload a file in document library using  Client object model with ECMA script Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What browser(s) are you using/supporting? Good luck trying to do it with anything less than an HTML 5 compatible browser!

Comment: Why should that be an issue? The Client Object Model for SharePoint is quite capable even without fancy HTML 5 features and jQuery extensions

Comment: I don't think the Ecmascript Client Object Model has a method to upload a file into the document library.  Most suggestions I have seen is to use the Copy.asmx webservice with jquery, but then you run into issues with serializing the file. There are some jquery plugins and AJAX-based solutions, but I find them cumbersome to get working.  HTML 5 browsers have FileReader class that greatly simplifies the process!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsazure/fr-fr/9146d127-87b0-4a64-86ec-11a4c2798f62/how-to-upload-file-to-document-library-using-javascript-client-object-model

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to start by doing a Google search for "sharepoint upload file javascript"

Comment: It is a bit ridiculous when prowl takes the time to write a question here, when the answer is a simple search away. Probably with a link back here aswell! :)